# Disabling the auto fade effect

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

Is it possible to disable the auto fading effect of iphone screen (ie. when we did not touch the screen then the display light of the screen fades).I need to disable this fading effect to stop the iphone going to sleep state.please help me.......thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

UIApplication class reference:

**idleTimerDisabled**

A Boolean value that controls whether the idle timer is disabled for the application.

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isIdleTimerDisabled) BOOL idleTimerDisabled
```

Discussion
The default value of this property is NO. When most applications have no touches as user input for a short period, the system puts the device into a "sleep” state where the screen dims. This is done for the purposes of conserving power. However, applications that don't have user input except for the accelerometer—games, for instance—can, by setting this property to YES, disable the “idle timer” to avert system sleep.

[...]